# How to access system trust store in Android 11+ programitically

Tags: android, keychain, mdm, multi-factor-authentication

I want to install a self-signed certificate in Android that will be system-wide accessible (accessible to other apps/browsers).

I have found that I can use keychain API, but for Android 11+ you can only add it manually so that does not work

I have looked into MDM, but certificate installation can only be done by a system app or signed as a system.

There are a lot of MFA apps Zscaler and Vmware Hub that do this to authenticate the user by installing certificate.

Is there a way to solve this?